# Loading CSV in Julia fails

Tags: csv, julia

I am trying to read a large DataFrame in Julia with `CSV.read(file, DataFrame)` and receive the following error:

```
ERROR: TaskFailedException

    nested task error: BoundsError: attempt to access 308-element Vector{BigFloat} at index [0]
    Stacktrace:
      [1] getindex
        @ .\array.jl:861 [inlined]
      [2] _scale(#unused#::Type{Float64}, v::BigInt, exp::Int64, neg::Bool)
        @ Parsers C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:524
      [3] scale(#unused#::Type{Float64}, v::BigInt, exp::Int64, neg::Bool)
        @ Parsers C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:408
      [4] parseexp
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:356 [inlined]
      [5] parsefrac
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:320 [inlined]
      [6] parsedigits
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:251 [inlined]
      [7] _parsedigits(#unused#::Type{Float64}, source::Vector{UInt8}, pos::Int64, len::Int64, b::UInt8, code::Int16, options::Parsers.Options, digits::BigInt, neg::Bool, startpos::Int64)
        @ Parsers C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:186
      [8] parsedigits
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:210 [inlined]
      [9] _parsedigits(#unused#::Type{Float64}, source::Vector{UInt8}, pos::Int64, len::Int64, b::UInt8, code::Int16, options::Parsers.Options, digits::UInt128, neg::Bool, startpos::Int64)
        @ Parsers C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:186
     [10] parsedigits
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:210 [inlined]
     [11] typeparser
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\floats.jl:179 [inlined]
     [12] xparse(::Type{Float64}, source::Vector{UInt8}, pos::Int64, len::Int64, options::Parsers.Options, ::Type{Float64})
        @ Parsers C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\Parsers.jl:316
     [13] xparse
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\Parsers\KmPKe\src\Parsers.jl:266 [inlined]
     [14] detect
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\utils.jl:470 [inlined]
     [15] detect
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\utils.jl:459 [inlined]
     [16] findchunkrowstart(ranges::Vector{Int64}, i::Int64, buf::Vector{UInt8}, opts::Parsers.Options, typemap::Dict{Type, Type}, downcast::Bool, ncols::Int64, rows_to_check::Int64, columns::Vector{CSV.Column}, origcoltypes::Vector{Type}, columnlock::ReentrantLock, stringtype::Any, totalbytes::Base.Threads.Atomic{Int64}, totalrows::Base.Threads.Atomic{Int64}, succeeded::Base.Threads.Atomic{Bool})
        @ CSV C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\detection.jl:383
     [17] macro expansion
        @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\detection.jl:470 [inlined]
     [18] (::CSV.var"#16#17"{Vector{UInt8}, Parsers.Options, Vector{Int64}, Int64, Vector{CSV.Column}, DataType, Dict{Type, Type}, Bool, Int64, Vector{Type}, ReentrantLock, Base.Threads.Atomic{Bool}, Base.Threads.Atomic{Int64}, Base.Threads.Atomic{Int64}, Int64})()
        @ CSV .\threadingconstructs.jl:178
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end(c::Channel{Any})
   @ Base .\task.jl:381
 [2] macro expansion
   @ .\task.jl:400 [inlined]
 [3] findrowstarts!(buf::Vector{UInt8}, opts::Parsers.Options, ranges::Vector{Int64}, ncols::Int64, columns::Vector{CSV.Column}, stringtype::Any, typemap::Dict{Type, Type}, downcast::Bool, rows_to_check::Int64)
   @ CSV C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\detection.jl:468
 [4] CSV.Context(source::CSV.Arg, header::CSV.Arg, normalizenames::CSV.Arg, datarow::CSV.Arg, skipto::CSV.Arg, footerskip::CSV.Arg, transpose::CSV.Arg, comment::CSV.Arg, ignoreemptyrows::CSV.Arg, ignoreemptylines::CSV.Arg, select::CSV.Arg, drop::CSV.Arg, limit::CSV.Arg, buffer_in_memory::CSV.Arg, threaded::CSV.Arg, ntasks::CSV.Arg, tasks::CSV.Arg, rows_to_check::CSV.Arg, lines_to_check::CSV.Arg, missingstrings::CSV.Arg, missingstring::CSV.Arg, delim::CSV.Arg, ignorerepeated::CSV.Arg, quoted::CSV.Arg, quotechar::CSV.Arg, openquotechar::CSV.Arg, closequotechar::CSV.Arg, escapechar::CSV.Arg, dateformat::CSV.Arg, dateformats::CSV.Arg, decimal::CSV.Arg, truestrings::CSV.Arg, falsestrings::CSV.Arg, stripwhitespace::CSV.Arg, type::CSV.Arg, types::CSV.Arg, typemap::CSV.Arg, pool::CSV.Arg, downcast::CSV.Arg, lazystrings::CSV.Arg, stringtype::CSV.Arg, strict::CSV.Arg, silencewarnings::CSV.Arg, maxwarnings::CSV.Arg, debug::CSV.Arg, parsingdebug::CSV.Arg, validate::CSV.Arg, streaming::CSV.Arg)
   @ CSV C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\context.jl:608
 [5] #File#25
   @ C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\file.jl:221 [inlined]
 [6] CSV.File(source::String)
   @ CSV C:\Users\mazoi\.julia\packages\CSV\jFiCn\src\file.jl:221
 [7] top-level scope
   @ REPL[16]:1
```

I think I can pinpoint the error to some rows that have strange mismatching types. I can read the data in Python and the problematic columns show `\\N`.

I tried to get around the issue by specifying `escapechar='\\'` but it didn't help. Any ways to get around these problematic rows or find a more robust package than `CSV.jl`? Thanks!

Update: added full Stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Can you give a more complete stacktrace of the error? Also, could you explain what you mean by "strange mismatching types"?

Comment: Just added the complete stacktrace. From what I see by loading the file in pandas with Python, the problematic rows have ```\\N``` (I think a missing value of sorts) where the other rows are ```int``` or ```string```. Those rows are actually not very useful for me but are part of the raw data. If I could skip or delete them, that would be great but how to do that in Julia if I cannot load the file?

Comment: Can you try with multi-threading disabled i.e. passing `ntasks = 1` to your `CSV.read` call?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Why did multi-threading disrupt the process though?

Comment: For multithreaded parsing, CSV.jl tries to split the workload between threads, by parsing different parts of the file. For that, it needs to correctly identify the starts of valid rows in the middle of the file, and messy files make that difficult. [Here's one of many related issues on Github](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/721#issuecomment-687564068).

Comment: Note that these days `rows_to_check` defaults to 30, and apparently that still wasn't enough with this file. You can also try re-enabling multi-threading (removing the `ntasks`), if you need it for performance, and passing a higher `rows_to_check`, for eg. 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file has fields that start with several digits (eg. SHA digest values), this may be due to [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/issues/1007). If so, a fix has been added to CSV.jl, but isn't available in a release yet.

In any case, the error occurs during parsing done for multithreaded processing of the file, so you can avoid it by passing `ntasks = 1` to the `CSV.read` call.